# How to access directly internet on WearOS app

Tags: java, android, database, kotlin, wear-os

I am looking for My data on wear OS app to send to my external apache server with php and mysql.

Ultimately I need watch sensor data in MySQL database, So i created a POST request page using php. How do I send POST request?

Note: I am not using mobile phone between WearOS app and My server. WearOS is connected to internet via WiFI

Please if you know any solution help me

FYI: I tried basic things given at https://developer.android.com/training/wearables 
Using Smart Watch with API level 23

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your watch system version is too old. I strongly recommend you to buy a new watch or try update to Wear OS 2.x (API25) if your device is still under maintain.

If you insist on using current device the only way to access the Internet is via mobile phone. You can not send HTTP requests directly.

But the old version system should not be able to connect the WiFi. Please confirm your version at first. If your API level equal or larger than 25,  you can access the Internet as same as phone using OkHttp or others you like.

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you please send any guidelines on okhttp or any other protocols with any example

Comment: @Astra We usually use [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) to request web API instead of using okhttp directly. However if you just want to send simple data it is a good idea that use okhttp only. See [docs](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)